# number of rounds passing choclate

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

We are playing a game where there are n children sitting in a circle. Each of them has some number of chocolates. The total number of chocolates are such that they can be divided equally among all children.

In one round any one of children passes one chocolate to the left or to the right. We need to answer, minimally how many such rounds will it take for all of them to have the same number of chocolates.

The number of children n and the number of chocolates with each of them is given.

What algorithm shall we apply??

Answer (score 0):

My heuristic would be:

```
while (not equally divided)
    find kid A with the most chocolates
    while (A has more that he should)
        find closest kid B with fewer than he should
            pass one from A to B and add to the number of moves (taking distance into account)
```

Comment: i doubt if that would be optimal.

Comment: I doubt too. What kind of answer are you looking for? An algorithm and mathematical proof that the algorithm is optimal?

Comment: I am looking an algorithm that find the optimal answer. I am not too keen on the mathematical proof.